# How to say 'to reach epidemic proportions', but with a positive connotation?

Tags: phrase-request

It seems *to reach epidemic proportions* is only used in negative contexts, usually associated with diseases (obesity), a negative, yet popular practice (suicidal behavior among adolescents), etc. I'd like to know if there is a phrase that can be used positively (e.g. blood donation).

Comment: _is increasingly gaining currency_, perhaps?

Comment: is _ubiquitous_?  _commonplace_?

Comment: Epidemic as an adjective tends to be negative because it refers to the way a highly infectious disease spreads. If you could give an example sentence where you would like to use it in a positive sense, it might help us come up with some better terms. For example, _"Awareness campaigns have caused blood donations to reach record levels."_ with "record" being used as an adjective meaning _surpassing all others_.

Comment: @ColleenV ; _to reach record levels_ is new to me and useful, but isn't there a hint of comparison with it? I mean there should be some other thing that _blood donation_ be compared with. Am I right? As for a context, my mind goes blank [midnight here!].

Comment: It might not be the phrase you're looking for. It means higher than all previous levels of donations.

Comment: How about *has reached epic proportions*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- is *catching on*
- is *trending* (or *trending up* or *becoming trendy*)
- has *gone viral* (but this might not be as widely usable as you want)